# JQuery Mobile document ready alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I spent hours trying to debug a jquery mobile page I had created and finally got it to work. I had put the script it in the data-role="page" class="page-map4" div. I was wondering why this was the case, I would rather this not be magic to me. This didn't matter if I accessed the page directly, only if I had accessed it from another JQuery Mobile page.

```
$('.page-map4').live("pageshow", function(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        } else {
              error('Geolocation not supported');
        }
});
```

**Question:** Why does the above script have to be in the page data-role div to work correctly when navigated from another JQuery Mobile page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For page events I simply do this in my jQuery code. This goes in a `<script>` tag-set in the `<head>` element of a page, after any document binding to the `$.mobile` global:

```
$('#YOUR_PAGE_ID').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
  yourGeoCode();
});
```

Comment: I had it in a script tag-set but it only seem to work correctly when pulled from the head and put into the data-role="page" div.

Comment: This solution works for me even in script tags within the body. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the pageinit event see this post '[Using jQuery Mobile – Remember to use pageinit() and not $(document).ready()](http://operationmobile.com/using-jquery-mobile-remember-to-use-pageinit-and-not-document-ready/)' for more information